# WIX: Create a fragment for features

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am creating a Windows Installer MSI using WIX. I want to separate files into different fragments, to have small chunks of code in each wxs file.

Currently I have below files:
- **Product.wxs** which contains Product, Package, MediaTemplate and Feature elements.
- **Directories.wxs** which contains folders structures and components to give permissions to user and remove folders on uninstall.

I want to take all my features out of **Product.wxs** too, and create it's own file, called **Features.wxs**.

Inside **Directories.wxs**, I have below line of code:

```
<Component Id="Component1" Guid="PUT_GUID_HERE" Directory="Subfolder">
  <CreateFolder>
    <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" ChangePermission="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" User="Users"/>
  </CreateFolder>
</Component>
```

With having above code, since I am referencing this Component in a Feature element, I am certain that my **Product.wxs** and **Directories** are linked.

But when I create a **Feature.wxs** file and move below lines of code to it:

```
<Feature Id="CreateDirectoriesFeature" Title="Feature1" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="Component1"/>
</Feature>
```

I don't know how/where to reference this fragment/features in my **Product.wxs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a FeatureGroup with FeatureRef elements and then in Product.wxs use a FeatureGroupRef to bring into scope.

Comment: Just the below simple line in Product is sufficient?
    <FeatureGroupRef Id="FG1"/>

Comment: The wxs containing the Product element is the "main" wxs file.  When you ref something in another wxs the entire wxs gets brought into scope.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials/tree/master/web-application/Installer for one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said above and it works perfectly :)

Comment: FWIW, I maintain an open source project called IsWiX.  One of it's features is to give you project templates / scaffolding.  It creates a solution structure so you don't have to worry about this right away.  There is no right or wrong way per say... it's just a way to do it quickly and easily so you can focus on other things.  It also includes graphical designers to do most of the heavy XML lifting.

Answer (score 0):

I put my Feature stuff in a different file as well, and the only thing that I need to reference them is the Feature's ID.

Here's a code example.  Here's an *entire* feature file that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
      <Feature Id="Feature_Name"
               Level="1">
          <ComponentRef Id="Component_Name"/>
      </Feature>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And here's how I reference it in *Product.wxs*.  I'll show you the entire file from the *MajorUpgrade* element to its bitter end:

```
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>
        <FeatureRef Id="Feature_Name"/>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

That's it.  Maybe you're not using *FeatureRef*?